# How to simulate a hidden Markov chain?

Tags: r, simulation, markov-process, copula

I want to simulate data from a 3-state hidden Markov chain with a known matrix of transition probabilities. Each state corresponds to a bivariate data with known marginals that the dependence between them is modeled by a copula. What is the best algorithm? Is there any function in `R` for such work?

Comment: The transition matrix (or transition kernel in the continuous case) represents conditional probabilities/densities, while the copula represents a joint distribution; to convert that to a transition matrix, you'll need to divide the joint by the relevant margin.

Answer (score 2):

My memory of how Markov chains work is pretty vague, so this may be utterly unhelpful -- I've created three functions below : trans.func is a helper function for gen.trans.matrix, which creates a transition matrix for n nodes.  Markov.sim takes two inputs: a transition matrix, and a desired duration length, d, and delivers simulated data from the Markov chain.  Hope the is enough to get you going --

```
trans.func = function(n){
  breaks = runif(n-1,0,1)
  breaks.s = breaks[order(breaks,decreasing = F)]
  trans = c(breaks.s[1],diff(c(breaks.s,1)))
  return(trans)
}


gen.trans.matrix = function(n){
  t(replicate(n,trans.func(n)))
}


markov.sim = function(mat, d){
  start = floor(runif(1,1,ncol(mat) + 1))  
  empty.vec = rep(NA,d)
  empty.vec[1] = start
  curr.node = start
  for(i in 2:d){
    random.draw = runif(1,0,1)
    next.node = (sum(random.draw > cumsum(mat[curr.node,])) + 1)
    curr.node = next.node
    empty.vec[i] = curr.node
  }
  return(empty.vec)
}

mat.temp = gen.trans.matrix(3)
markov.sim(mat.temp, 50)
```